# How to iterate through array of strings from database Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, json

I save an array of strings to my rails database, but when I go to use it in the view, I believe it is printing the string definition of the array. Am I dealing with JSON here? (aka when it saves to the database is it just an array wrapped in a string?)

How do I have it so that in my view, it simply displays the items?

```
<%= record.items %>
```

displays inside my html tag:

```
["item1", "item2", "item3"]
```

I tried iterating through `record.items.each do |item|` but that did not work.

Comment: What does `<%= record.items.class %>` return, what are you currently seeing with `object.each`?

Comment: String. I save the array of strings to my database so the column type is of String. I think that is the right way to go about saving an array of strings to your db?

Comment: "The right way" depends on which database you're using. PostgreSQL supports arrays natively so you'd make a `text[]` column and everything would work, other relational databases would probably want you to use `serialize` to jam a pile of YAML into a text column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're saving an "exact" array as a String, then [`Array#each`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-each) won't work, because isn't a method in the String class.

Maybe isn't the best option, but you could use JSON.parse and this way get your array and be able to iterate over each object inside:

```
require 'json'

str = '["item1", "item2", "item3"]'
JSON.parse(str).each { |item| p item }
# "item1"
# "item2"
# "item3"
```

In order this work your string must be an array, in your example the second item is missing its double quote.

You could consider working with serialization or array data types depending on you current database.

Comment: where are you supposed to put that `require 'json'` line?

Comment: If working with Rails you don't need to require it, try without it.

Comment: Are you sure that's JSON? Looks more like `some_array.inspect` output to me and that would suggest using `serialize` or an array column in the database instead of manually mucking around with strings.

Comment: Am I? I don't know, if is the result of inspect in an array then it'd look more like `"[\"item1\", \"item2\", \"item3\"]"`. More than helping with this I guess I can't, I mentioned some hints to bear in mind.

Answer (score 0):

A better approach to your issue is to [serialize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html) your items column. I think by default it's Array but you can use Hash or JSON.

```
class Record < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :items
end
```

Calling `record.items` returns the data exactly the way you need. If you go with this you'll have to update your old records to support it.